# how can we call webservice through background service

Tags: android

i am using a web service. i have to start that particular service at every 6 hrs interval, automatically . i want to perform this task with alarm manager. but i have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question covers the general issues. You will need to look elsewhere for the details of wiring up the web service: [Android: How to periodically send location to a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775628/android-how-to-periodically-send-location-to-a-server)