# Location tracking in background in android

Tags: android

I am working on an application which fetch the location details in a periodic manner..
i have tried service and broadcastreciever but failed to achieve the location details in particular time frame say 30mins or so.. can any help or suggest me some thing through which i can achieve the location details again and again ..
Thnks in adv

Comment: have you considered to declare your service as a `LocationListener` which gets updated everytime the GPS sensor retrieves a new location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the Alarm Manager?
You can do the following to update location periodically:

1.Register an alarm manager that will call a service every 30 mins.

2.Make sure you  acquire a wake lock so that the device wakes up from sleep.

3.The alarm manager takes a pending intent which in turn calls a BroadcastReciever/Service when the alarm is triggered.

4.From this BroadCastReciever call the Service to that will update your location.
[Check this question for the complete code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775628/android-how-to-periodically-send-location-to-a-server)[Also this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407309/send-current-location-to-server-periodically-in-android)