# How to make an Android App keep running when I press the back button or home button or lock the screen?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an android app. So I would like to know how to make the app keep running when I press the back button or home button or lock the screen(just like a music player app).
Currently when I press the back button or home button or lock the screen , the app pauses the activity and resumes when I open the app again. I want the app to keep running in the background until I stop it manually from the app(just like a music player app).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable back button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keep application running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494222/keep-application-running-in-background)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android background music service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service)

Comment: using background service