# Firebase Realtime Database auto increase value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to auto increment a value of firebase realtime database. without running app.

That means, let a user have point, and that point is stored in firebase realtime database. I want this point will auto increase also when the app will closed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into the Firebase Realtime Database to auto-change values at specific times.

But Firebase has an integration with Cloud Functions, that can be used to trigger (small) bits of JavaScript code in conditions you define. One common use-case that developers use Cloud Functions for is to implement code that runs on a certain time, or at certain intervals. For more on this use-case, see [Cloud Functions for Firebase trigger on time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790735/cloud-functions-for-firebase-trigger-on-time)

Answer (score 1):

From your explanation this seems to be an issue which can be easily solved by keeping the app running in background. For this purpose [look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494222/keep-application-running-in-background)

Quoting the answer from above link I gave here,

> A very simple answer for your problem is to use [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). It will allow you to perform variety of tasks while being in background and is your best bet for sending your location/data to server silently.

Also [read this answer for help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775628/android-how-to-periodically-send-location-to-a-server/2779589#2779589)

Although both the answers are related to location update but they can be easily extended to fulfill your requirements.

**Hint:** 
The above quoted answers are sending the data to a server at frequent intervals. Send your data to Firebase server when the data-field is changed.

Comment: I want to do my process without using phone time or calendar. Because it is depend on user phone time. This system will be cracked by changing user phone time

Comment: @HasanToufiqAhamed without running the code anywhere, it will NOT be possible to do anything, the best way is to put the app in background and carry out the work, I think.

Comment: Thank your sir, for your recommend