# Sending Geo Locations periodically to server

Tags: android, service, gps

I have a list of registered users . I want to compare their location with the current user . I know I need to send the location coordinates periodically to the server. This would be done within a service . I am not sure at what time I should obtain the location coordinates of the users :- At the registration time or login time.

Please provide me some suggestions what is the right time to save the location details into the server.

I am new to android. 
(Pardon me if this is something silly I am asking for).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to periodically send location to a server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775628/android-how-to-periodically-send-location-to-a-server)