# What should be used for continuos background work in android app? service or intent service

Tags: android, service, location

In my application, I would like to send user location to server continuously for every 5 minuets,.. I don't know much about services.. I would appreciate if someone can help me.. Please give me some references to create service and intentservice examples. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775628/android-how-to-periodically-send-location-to-a-server

Comment: Did not explore well.. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `Service` for that. Use `START_STICKY` to ensure it doesn't get killed permanently and/or set an Interval starting the `Service` using `AlarmManager`.

However you probably should reconsider doing this at all. No one wants an app which uses RAM and network bandwidth all the time and leaks personal data.