# How to run android service continuously?

Tags: java, android

I want to run a service to send some data to server continuously, but when my watch is sleep mode (when screen is off) app shouldn't stop the service.

Comment: Give some code?

Comment: Using broadcast receiver you can detect the on/off of the watch. Then you can start and stop the service accordingly. This is a basic implementation and I suggest you to add more details about the try outs you have done, when you put in a questions. SO community is not that responsive to such generic questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `WakefulService`. This service will keep running in the background. This is called a `Wake lock`. You can find more about that [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775628/android-how-to-periodically-send-location-to-a-server/2779589#2779589) topic could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try!

*Start* a **Service** and ***return*** **START_STICKY** in **onStartCommand** basically it tell android to restart your service when it is killed, but it doesn't guarantee that the service will run indefinitely.

Also use **StartForeground()** to give your service foreground priority it will keep your service alive as long as it can.

Comment: Well. It may help someone. Thanks